# Angular 4+ form validation

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, writing a page with form but with the validation i am facing a  situation which doesn't seems suitable for real world application.

I have written a code like below,

```
this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl('default first name', [
    Validators.maxLength(20), 
    Validators.required
  ]),
  lastName: new FormControl('default last name', [
    Validators.maxLength(20), 
    Validators.required
  ])
});
```

now it has become compulsory for me to supply 'default first name', cause the field is marked with Validator.required.

Is there anyway through which i can make field mandatory without supplying the default value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ```new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.required])```

Comment: empty string[ ' ' ] is also violates the validation, and if a supply space in single quotes I don't get the place holder which i have defined in html.

Comment: you should check the validation when the form is touched, for e.g: ```*ngIf="!myForm.get('firstName').valid && myForm.get('firstName').touched"```

Comment: check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-6tasfd)

Comment: <div>
      First Name
      <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
      <br>
      <label *ngIf="!myForm.get('firstName').valid myForm.get('firstName').touched  signupForm.get('firstName').invalid" [ngClass]="'error field-error'"  >{{signup_errmsg.firstName}}</label>
      <br>
    </div>

Comment: what is this? doesn't have any operation && or || and it's not correct condition for check form validation.

Comment: @FatemeFazli, 
you may be correct, but i did this because it gives me error while putting condition.

Comment: what error? you can fork my stackblitz and change it to what you want and share it with me.

Comment: based on pic you are using 2 forms: myform and signupform it's not correct, you have only one form.

Comment: even after changing it to signupForm i have the same issue.

Comment: now check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-6tasfd) and do like this, then tell me if there is any problem.

Comment: @FatemeFazli,
can you please tell me how can i share my project to you over stackblitz ?
i already have my project on github :
https://github.com/piyushvj/dream-project.git

Comment: no need to share your whole project just change my stackblitz code to your form part of your code and select fork and share the link.

Comment: i guess i am not able to matchup it properly please look at the link 

Editor URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vszlw3

App URL : https://angular-6-reactive-forms-6tasfd.stackblitz.io

Embaded URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-6tasfd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts

many thanks for your kind support.

Comment: i saw your code for e.g your first form item should be ```<div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':signupForm.get('firstName').touched && signupForm.get('firstName').invalid}" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              <div>First Name is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>```.

Comment: even after placing the same code you provided I can see the error message. [snap attached]

Comment: it's OK, when you touch the input it should show the error message and it's correct. if you still didn't touch the input the error is not shown.

Comment: code is now available on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfgu2m

Comment: now check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-speh8h.

Comment: can you see this on stackblitz ? 
once I refresh the page, i get the error message even i didn't touch the field.

Comment: i corrected it and it's now OK check my last link.

Comment: Yeah it is working now.....

many thanks @FatemeFazli.
you are just awesome <3

Is there any way that i can connect you directly, for any of my future query !

Comment: you'r welcome, i'll post it as an answer, ask your questions here, i'm always here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try to set touch condition in your form, add `signupForm.get('firstName').touched` :

```
<div>
   First Name
   <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
   <br>
   <label *ngIf="signupForm.get('firstName').invalid && signupForm.get('firstName').touched" [ngClass]="'error'">{{signup_errmsg.firstName}}</label>
   <br>
</div>
```